# Change Number Format In Smarty For Displaying

Tags: php, smarty

I want to format the number in smarty. Can anyone help me on this?

What i have in smarty variable is

`31131`

What i want to display is

`31,131`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use PHP's built-in function [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format):

```
$num = 31131;
$num = number_format($num);

echo $num;
```

Output:

```
31,131
```

The Smarty way:

Define your number first:

```
$smarty->assign('number', 31131);
```

Now, in your template file, you can do:

```
{$number|number_format}
```

Output:

```
31,131
```

See the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl) for more examples.

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/9KGEKq5E)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the php `number_format` function in smarty

```
{$number|number_format}
```